# Remove frame in Edit Mode

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

I'm trying to create a truncated cube. However when I switch to *Edit Mode*, the original cube remains, and I'm only able to select its faces, instead of my truncated one. How do I remove this frame?

[image]

Comment: you have to apply the modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the modifier before you can edit it in edit mode. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks guys, this worked out! Bit of a silly mistake here :').

Comment: I'm glad it worked! P.S: Please accept my answer as the answer to your question. Thanks! :)